# vanishing higher cohomology group for property T group?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Given a countable discrete group $G$ with [Kazhdan's property (T)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kazhdan%27s_property_%28T%29), consider $\mathbb{C}G$ or $l^2(G)$ as a left $G$-module, then we can consider the [group cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#H2),

Is it known that $H^n(G, l^2(G))=0, H^n(G, \mathbb{C}(G))=0,~~ \forall n>1$?

I am mainly interested in the $n=2$ case.

Comment: If $\Gamma$ is a lattice in a symmetric space of dimension $2d$, then I think $H^d(\Gamma,\ell^2(\Gamma))$ is known nonzero, for the $d$-th $\ell^2$ Betti number is nonzero. For instance, if $\Gamma$ is a lattice in $SL_3(\mathbf{R})$ then $H^4(\Gamma,\ell^2(\Gamma))$ is nonzero whilst it has Property T. For $n=2$ and $\ell^2$, this does not work but maybe we should look hyperbolic groups with T and cohomological dimension 2.

Comment: @YCor, you mean for n=2, $G=SL_3(\mathbb{Z})$, the cohomology group vanishes?

Comment: the second $\ell^2$-Betti number of $SL_3(\mathbf{Z})$ is zero. This maybe implies that $H^2$ of $\ell^2(\Gamma)$ vanishes but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Regarding the same question with constant coefficients: any uniform lattice in $Sp(n,1)$ has a finite index subgroup with nonzero second Betti number, see Corollary 6.5 of [J.-S. Li, Nonvanishing theorems for the cohomology of certain arithmetic quotients, J. Reine Angew. Math. 428 (1992)]. Of course, they have property (T). Maybe some universal coefficients theorem would then imply the same for ${\mathbb C}G$ or $\ell^2(G)$. coefficients.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, I am not able to download the paper you mentioned right now, if I understand your remark correctly, you mean there exists a property $T$ group $G$ with $H^2(G, \mathbb{Z})\neq 0$?

Comment: @Jiang: no, I mean that there is a group $G$ with property (T) such that $H^2(G,\mathbb R)\neq 0$ where $\mathbb R$ is given the structure of a trivial $G$-module. This result is mentioned on page 1170 of http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0005302.

Comment: @IgorBelegradek, thanks a lot for clarification!

Comment: Why do you need a finite index subgroup? if you have any lattice in $Sp(n,1)$ then the universal covering yields a 2-cocycle, which remains non-trivial on the lattice. (If it were trivial on the lattice, it would be trivial on any finite index subgroup). One argument that the 2-cocycle is nontrivial is that the extension, being a lattice in the universal covering of $Sp(n,1)$ which also has T by S.P.Wang/Serre's theorem, has T, which implies that the 2-cocycle is nontrivial on the lattice in $Sp(n,1)$. Anyway this is very far from the original question.

Comment: PS: in this example, you both have $H^2(\Gamma,\mathbf{Z})$ and $H^2(\Gamma,\mathbf{R})$ nonzero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are interested in cohomology with coefficients in the group ring $\mathbb CG$, then you should know the Bieri-Eckmann theory of duality for a group of finite cohomological dimension. The group ring is a bimodule, with commuting left and right actions of the group. Taking cohomology uses up one of these actions, but the other action makes the cohomology a $G$-module (or complex thereof) and there is an isomorphism $H^i(G;M)\cong H_{n-i}(G; M\otimes D)$, where $D$ is the $n$ is the homological dimension and $D$ is the dualizing complex, the cohomology with coefficients in the group ring.

In particular, if the group has a classifying space that is a oriented closed manifold of dimension $n$ (a case that probably predates Bieri-Eckmann), cohomology satisfies Poincaré duality, so the dualizing module is $\mathbb Z$ concentrated in a single degree; that is, $H^n(G;\mathbb ZG)\cong \mathbb Z$ and the cohomology vanishes in other degrees. So if $G$ is a cocompact torsion-free lattice in $SL_3(\mathbb R)$, it has property T and $H^5(G;\mathbb ZG)\cong \mathbb Z$.

More general than a PD group is a (Bieri-Eckmann) duality group where $H^*(G;\mathbb ZG)$ is concentrated in the top degree, though not cyclic. And Bieri-Eckmann prove for general groups subject to finiteness conditions that the top cohomology is non-trivial. So any lattice in a Lie group with property T gives an example of a property T group with nontrivial cohomology. In particular, I believe that $SL_3(\mathbb Z)$ has virtual dimension 3, so that gives an example with $H^3(G; \mathbb ZG)$ nontrivial. I do not believe that there are any lattices of dimension 2 in Lie groups with T. I suspect that lattices are all duality groups, so the cohomology of the group ring vanishes below the top dimension.

YCor mentions 2-dimensional groups with property T. The Bierri-Eckmann theory shows that these have nontrivial $H^2(G;\mathbb ZG)$.

---

If you want something useful to come out of $H^*(G; \ell^2G)$, you should not use ordinary cohomology, a tool for discrete coefficients, but you should change your definitions to take into account the topology. Study the theory of $L^2$ cohomology for suggestions. It may have a good definition already, but I think it usually restricts to coefficients with trivial action.

---

A question came up in the comments of an example of a property T group with nontrivial second cohomology with trivial coefficients. An easy source of second cohomology classes are Kähler forms. The natural metric on a Hermitian symmetric space is Kähler. For example, $Sp_{2g}(\mathbb R)/U(g)$ is a Hermitian symmetric space. Thus $A_g=Sp_{2g}(\mathbb Z)\backslash Sp_{2g}(\mathbb R)/U(g)$, the moduli of principally polarized abelian varieties is Kähler, and the Kähler class is nontrivial for $g>1$. If instead we take a cocompact lattice, the quotient is closed and the Kähler class is nontrivial for all $g$; moreover, it is easy to see that it is nontrivial, since a power of the Kähler form is the volume form, which is now cohomologically nontrivial. But we must take $g>1$ to get property T.

Comment: No, the definition of $H^*(G,\pi)$ for a unitary representation (such as $\ell^2(\Gamma)$) does not involve the topology when $\Gamma$ is a discrete group. Then there is a notion of reduced topology $H^*(\Gamma,\pi)$ taking into account the topology, where $\bar{H^n}(\Gamma,\pi)$ is the quotient of $H^n(\Gamma,\pi)$ by the closure of $\{0\}$. A standard reference for this is Guichardet's book.

Comment: @YCor, could you give me the reference on the property T group $G$ you mentioned such that $H^2(G;\mathbb{Z}G)$ is nontrivial? Thanks.

Comment: @Jiang Did I claim this? I can't find where.

Comment: @YCor, in Ben's answer above, -3 paragraph, maybe there is some misunderstanding?

Comment: @Jiang: so I didn't say that $H^2(G,\mathbf{Z}G))\neq 0$, but Ben said it. I said that there are f.g. groups with cohomological dimension 2 and Property T. These are Gromov's random groups for some model in density in $]1/3,1/2[$ (see references in http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.3854). Ben's claim seems (?) to be that a (1-ended ?) f.g. group with cohomological dimension 2 has nonzero $H^2(G,\mathbf{Z}G)$ according to Bieri-Eckmann theory, maybe he has a reference.

Comment: @BenWieland, could you give me a reference why the group mentioned by YCor has nontrivial $H^2(G, \mathbb{Z}G)$?

Comment: Ken Brown, Cohomology of Groups, VIII 6.7. Or his notes, 4.3: https://www.math.cornell.edu/~kbrown/papers/cohomology_hangzhou.pdf

Comment: @BenWieland, thanks, I would check that.

Comment: @BenWieland, I checked the references you mentioned, but I do not know why the group mentioned by YCor is of type FP. Could you please explain this?

Comment: The paper says that the group has an aspherical presentation complex. This is a finite classifying space for the group. It gives a resolution of $\mathbb Z$ by $\mathbb Z[G]$-modules.