# Reference on calculation of 2nd cohomology group

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finitely generated, infinite, countable discrete nonamenable group with zero first Betti number, I.e., $H^1(G, \ell^2(G))=0$, e.g., $G=F_2\times F_2$, the product of free groups of two generators, any product groups with one to be nonamenable, property (T) groups, inner amenable groups, wreath product groups like $\mathbb{Z}\wr F_2$, etc.

I want to know whether there are some examples on concrete computation of the second cohomology group $H^2(G, \mathbb{Z}G)$.

I only care the nontrivial case.

A related question is asked [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178102/).